# Interaction between two populations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider $m$ populations with densities $n_{k}(t)$ at time $t$ that compete for a unique food resource that is renovated at constant rate, $K > 0$, and consumed by the members of each population at a rate $a_{k} > 0$. The the total consumption is $ \sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}n_{j}(t)$ and the lost is $ K - \sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}n_{j}(t)$, suppose that the rate of reproduction is given by $ \frac{1}{n_{k}} \frac{dn_{k}}{dt} = c_{k}( K - \sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}n_{j}(t)), c_{k} > 0$.

Show for two populations that if $n_{k}(0)$ is such that $K - \sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}n_{j}(0) \ge 0$ then the populations tend to an equilibrium.

Calculate $n_{k}(\infty)$ for the populations.

Can somebody help? I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I think "replenished" maybe an improvement upon "renovated"

Comment: @Mason This is not a PDE system, but a [Competitive Lotka-Volterra system of ODEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations)

Comment: Thanks. I made that comment when this was tagged PDE. I am not sure I recall how to solve such systems of ODEs. Is attempting to integrate directly going to be fruitless?

Comment: @Mason In general, rather fruitless (perhaps besides some extremely exceptional cases). See the Wikipedia article: there is a good survey of methods there.